# Do I have to include license in artwork that uses a font licensed Apache License v2.00?

Tags: apache-2.0, license-notice, font

If I create a artwork (images) using a font licensed Apache License v2.00, and i include this artwork in a website (commercial),
do I have to include the license somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache license does not discuss fonts and typefaces explicitly, and the intellectual property situation for them is quite uneven internationally.

In many jurisdictions there is a strong distinction between a *typeface* (the visual appearance) and a *font* (the computer program that renders a typeface). Whereas the font may be copyright-protected, the typeface itself is not. However, a typeface may be protected by design patents. This is the situation in the U.S. Other jurisdictions like the U.K. copyright-protect typefaces directly, but do not see a document set in that typeface as a copy of the typeface.

So it's complicated, and depends on your jurisdiction. However, in nearly all cases it will be OK to set text in your artwork in a typeface by using an Apache-licensed font. For example, using the typeface as lettering in a comic or for text in an infographic would likely be fine. Assuming that the rendered text is not a derivative work of the font, you are not obligated to show any license notices.

Note that the situation may be quite different for commercial fonts (which may have usage restrictions in their license), or when distributing a font as a webfont. It may also matter whether your artwork consists only of the font, e.g. in a wordmark.